# Adding sidenav to Angular project

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to add the `Angular` Material sidenav to my `Angular 8` application.

I was able to get the `Angular Material sidenav` to appear on the left side of my existing `SPA` landing page.. the problem now is that while the side nav is on the left like it should be, it is causing some problems with my existing components.

```
<section><nav>
<app-header></app-header>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<br>
<app-weather></app-weather> //where the sidenav is located
<app-home></app-home> //my bootstrap carousel with images
<br>
<app-bio></app-bio>
<br>
<app-date-time></app-date-time>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
</section>
```

I no longer see my nav bar and my `bootstrap` carousel is pushed down and the images are hardly being displayed (I only see the bottom part where the carousel image placeholders are located).

I tried to use the CSS justify-content/position to push the sidebar more to the left but this didn't work for me.

Does someone know how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to the css file of the side-nav container and added some pixels to "right". Doing this put the side nav to the left of the navbar (appears now). I now see the images in my bootstrap carousel perfectly.

```
    .example-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 5;
```

}